# bootstrap styles missing after deploy to Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Based on the googling I've been doing for the past two days, I am joining the hundreds (if not thousands) of people who lost bootstrap styling when deploying to Heroku.  As is true of everyone else, the bootstrap styling works fine on the local machine, but is absent on the deployed heroku site.  I am stumped.  I am using rails 4.2.4 and ruby 2.2.3.  (I am also using RubyMine if that makes a difference. I don't think it does. I tried a deploy with "plain" git and sublime and it made no difference.)  Here is what I have done:

1. I have links to the maxcdn in my application.html.erb (both css and js)
2. I changed the name of application.css to application.scss (and I also tried application.css.scss)
3. I added the @import directives (boostrap-sprockets and bootstrap) to application.scss
4. I added //= require bootstrap-sprockets to application.js (after the turbolinks entry).
5. I added gems bootstrap-sass, autoprefixer-rails, and rails_12factor and did bundle install
6. I changed config.assets.compile from false to true in config/environments/production.rb
7. I also tried precompiling assets, but the bootstrap styling was still missing.

I believe that is all I should have to do to get it working.  As mentioned above, it works fine on the local machine.

I've tried many solutions suggested on the web that have not worked.  It's hard to tell which ones are applicable because this seems to have been a problem for several years (my google searches return questions like this, and suggested solutions, from 2012 to the present).  I'm sure some of those solutions are no longer applicable (for rails v4).

As usual, any help is appreciated.

Comment: From my experience, the only method in your list that worked was the maxcdn links. Did you get rid of any other bootstrap includes when you tried the maxcdn ?

Comment: No.  I used all of the changes together.  I have not tried just adding the maxcdn and eliminating all of the other changes.

Comment: If this wasn't ironic, you should try it (I'm saying that because it really sounds ironic, but I might have misunderstood)

Comment: I'm desperate.  Per your suggestion, I just tried removing the references to bootstrap in application.scss and application.js.  No joy.

Comment: I'm gonna write an answer describing how I included it, maybe it can help you

Comment: Thank you.  I'll even accept magic incantations if that will work!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to start a project from scratch and to just make Bootstrap working in production. I succeeded to do that with the maxcdn method.

Here is what I did to include the bootstrap maxcdn :

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**, at the end of the `<head>` tag :

```
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

I only did this, and nothing else. It worked like a charm, even in production on Heroku.

Comment: Well, that worked!! I successfully deployed a bootstrap demonstration page to Heroku will all styling intact!  Thanks for the assistance.  Now I just need to strip out all of the bootstrap specific stuff that I added to my other app.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to mark it as answered.  I don't see a button or link to that.  It may be because I have so few reputation points.

Comment: There is a "checked" symbol that you can click, on the left of the answers. Here is a picture : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: OK.  Sorry. That graphic was a little too subtle for me!  Usually people communicate with me using a 2x4!

Comment: Thanks ! :) 
(But I don't have any idea what a 2x4 is)

Answer (score 1):

I did not have to "Try to start a project from scratch".  Just adding the

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to run this commands in your CLI

`rake assets:clobber
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
git add .
git commit -m "Precompile assets in preparation for deploying to Heroku."
git push heroku master`

works like a magic to me!

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped with this issue today. The thing that helped me it was checking version for node and yarn(Of course, if you use it). It makes sense to point out my main stack that I worked with today.

```
gemfile:
Rails 6.1.4, ruby '3.0.0', 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'

package.json:
 "node": "15.14.0", "yarn": "1.22.15", "bootstrap": "4.5.0"
```

So the bootstrap worked as expected for development but not for production(heroku)

To be in short: the difference was in versions of node and yarn on development and production env. Heroku used default versions if you do not set them in package.json. For my case heroku had a bit lower than my local.

I've added the next part of json into package.json and heroku takes it and setups it too after deploy. Thats all.

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "15.14.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.15"
  }
```