# Bootstrap styling not showing when deploying to heroku a RoR application with React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am using Ruby on Rails with React and I am deploying to Heroku. I have been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351423/bootstrap-styles-missing-after-deploy-to-heroku) already and the responses are not helping me. In my application.html.erb file I have

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'Index' %>
  </head>
```

And I am importing bootstrap as well in the main component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import { createStore} from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from '../components/App';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';


const store = createStore(rootReducer, { }, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  );
});
```

When deploying to Heroku only the bootstrap classes are not being styled, although they are showing as classes in the DOM. No errors are showing developer tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the assets pipeline in rails 6 with Webpacker try the following it should make it work:

Step 1:

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.3.1 jquery popper.js
```

Step 2:
in `config/webpack/environment.js` add the following:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

Step 3:
in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` add the following:

```
import 'bootstrap'
import './src/application.scss'
```

step 4:
create the following folder `app/javascript/packs/src` and create the file `application.scss` and place `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'`;

This should fix the problem and configure Rails 6 with Webpack for production.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding the link into your layout don't import it, and vice versa. I'd say leave the link up and cut it from the component & make sure nothing else is sneakily importing duplicates anywhere else.

A surefire way to get it working is to save it to your /assets/stylesheets directory and make sure your application.css.scss file is importing it either through `*= require_tree .` or by name, if you didn't mind sacrificing the potential caching benefit of having the cdn serve it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding the bootstrap link to my

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>.
```

The link is for bootstrap 5. I hope that works for you too